# Trying to get list of views in folder in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, scandir

I'm using Codeigniter, and all I'm trying to do is to get a list of all the views in a particular folder within the "views" folder.

Here's my code, inside of my controller:

```
$this->data['sections'] = array_diff( scandir('/application/views/portfolio/embeds/work/'), array('.', '..') );
```

And here is the error message I'm getting:

> Message: scandir(/application/views/portfolio/embeds/work/): failed to open dir: No such file or directory
>
> Filename: controllers/Work.php
>
> Line Number: 54

Am I just forgetting something? Or is there maybe a way to set a relative path from the location of my controller? Because using the path "../views/portfolio/embeds/work/" doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: `$this->data['sections'] = array_diff( scandir( APPATH .'views/portfolio/embeds/work' ), array( '.', '..' ) );` Use `APPPATH` constant that'd give you absolute path to the application directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add in the base path of your installation. Currently you are asking scandir to read the directory /application on your web server, when you most likely want /var/www/example.com/application

Try this:

```
 scandir(FCPATH . 'application/views/portfolio/embeds/work')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like in a foreach loop and use FCPATH

```
$files = array_diff(scandir(FCPATH .'application/views/portfolio/embeds/work'), array('.', '..'));

foreach ($files as $file) {
    echo $file;
}
```